# Proper way to access a object property in a jquery-tmpl {{each}} statement

Tags: jquery, jquery-templates

I'm using [jquery-tmpl](http://api.jquery.com/category/plugins/templates/).  My object model is simple -- SalesProspect, which contains a collection of SalesProspectAction objects.  Both of those objects have a field named Status.  How do I get the child's Status in the [each](http://api.jquery.com/template-tag-each/) loop?  It always pulls the parent's.

```
<script id="tmplActions" type="text/x-jquery-tmpl">
    <p>${GuestName}</p>
    <table class="stdtable" cellpadding="3" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
        <thead><tr><td>Date</td><td>By</td><td>Changed To</td><td>Notes</td></tr></thead>
        <tbody>
            {{each(i,action) SalesProspectActions}}
            <tr>
                <td>${DateCreated}</td>
                <td>${CreatedBy}</td>
                <td>${Status}</td>
                <td>${Notes}</td>
            </tr>
        {{/each}}
        </tbody>
    </table>
</script>
```

I've tried a few different things, like `{$action.Status}`, etc., but no luck.

Comment: I know you elludd to trying but since your example is incorrect i want to make sure... you used `${action.Status}` and that did not work (not the location of the `$`)?

Comment: Doh, can't believe I missed that -- you are correct.  Feel free to add that as an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As noted in my comment (despite the typos...) the syntax is `${action.Status}` NOT `{$action.Status}`.

Answer (score 2):

are you sure that this code doesn't work?

```
{{each(i,action) SalesProspectActions}}
    <tr>
        <td>${action.Status}</td>
    </tr>
{{/each}}
```

Answer (score 0):

object can be passed as template option. Here is what I did in my project:

http://codekiku.blogspot.in/2012/04/jquery-template-options-pass-objects-or.html